# spreadsheet of all files in a directory

Tags: batch-file, spreadsheet, windows-explorer

We are finalising a legal matter and need to provide a list of all correspondence for the matter.
I've got a folder on my computer with ALL of the emails, word docs, pdf's, jpg's etc. and wish to quickly create a spreadsheet listing the file name, type, size, data created.

Can this be done with a batch file?   If so, how?

Comment: Are there any subfolders? Are there any other files in that folder and/or subfolders that shouldn't be listed in the spreadsheet?

Comment: no subufolder, no unwanted files.   Absolutely everthing in the folder needs to be listed.   There is about 2,600 files.

I've tried `dir *.* > FileList.csv`, but it doesn't really seperate the details I want into columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic version that should get you going.

It uses `for` to collect info about files in a folder (and all subfolders), outputting as csv.

You could adjust (or ask for help in adjusting), such as making pretty names for the file type. The timestamp this batch gives you is 'date modified' rather than 'date created'. If that's critical we can work around that too.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set DATA_DIR=%1
if not defined DATA_DIR (
  echo You must specify a folder with your data files.
  exit /b 1
)
echo FILE, TYPE, SIZE, TIMESTAMP
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /s /b /a-d %DATA_DIR%') do (
  echo %%~f, %%~xf, %%~zf, %%~tf
)
```

To use:

```
    C:\...\> make_csv.cmd c:\data > FileList.csv
```

And you will get something like FileList.csv:

```
FILE, TYPE, SIZE, TIMESTAMP
C:\data\that one.doc, .doc, 0, 10/05/2013 11:14 AM
C:\data\this one.txt, .txt, 6, 10/05/2013 11:14 AM
C:\data\sub\another.jpg, .jpg, 6, 10/05/2013 11:15 AM
```

Comment: @Endoro - I did say that in the answer, and offer to go further with it, if the OP wanted it, which she didn't.

Comment: I very much apologize for my ugly mistake :facepalm:. If you would edit your answer, I will change the voting.

Comment: @Endoro - no worries - it's a better answer now anyway, without the uncertainty around the timestamp, so thanks. :)