# .pes file details needed to create directory listing

Tags: list, batch-file, attributes, spreadsheet, dst-embroidery

I'm attempting to get a listing of my embroidery design files (format .pes) from a specific directory. I have started with the information on this post - [spreadsheet of all files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473587/spreadsheet-of-all-files-in-a-directory)  but wish to add a couple of attributes

Using an explorer-type software (specifically Stitch Era Universal Explorer), I know that within the file information is stored Height, Width and Stitch Count (among other things.) How can I modify the batch file to include that information for each file? There must be a way to determine what the names of the file attributes are, but I can't seem to find it.

Thank you so much for any assistance you might offer!
Warm regards,
Penny

Comment: put an example how you get `Height, Width and Stitch Count` ...?

Comment: You need to use a command line tool built for .pes files that lists these items, and perhaps other details, and then a batch file can extract them from the console output.

Answer (score 0):

You need a command line tool built for pes files that could list those aspects. I am the author of [EmbroidePy/pyembroidery](https://github.com/EmbroidePy/pyembroidery) and it can read those attributes. PES files internally contain a number of metadata elements, in version 4+ of the format these are Label, Author, Keywords, Category, Comments. Other aspects like height, width, stitch count, are stored in the stitch block within the file. But, usually most software will simply recalculate these values by parsing file. Moreover because some formats do not include these elements in a consistent fashion and you're better off reading the stitches and calculating the data as that would be the only way to get that information for files like .exp (expanded Melco).

Such functionality with the project would require like a dozen lines of code, if anybody modernly comes across this, and would want to achieve these same ends. Also, and it's noteworthy, there's really not any other way to do this other than an open source project that can parse a few dozen embroidery formats.

---

I have updated the [command line tool](https://github.com/EmbroidePy/pyembroidery-CLI) to allow this, it will load the embroidery files and give you the requested information you want with a format tag.

`pyemb.py -q -i * -f "%f %x,%y"`

You'd often just pipe this to a text file.

`pyemb.py -q -i * -f "%f,%x,%y" > embroidery_statistics.csv`